# Difference between (string == "") and (string.length() ==0)

Tags: java, string

```
public static String[] myfunc(String s){
    if (s == null) return null;
    if (s == "") return new String[0];
    //code.. 
    //this code will not run if s == "" 
}
```

I intended `s == ""` to cover all the empty strings.
But there seems to be cases where `s != ""` but `s.length() == 0`
What is the difference between `s == ""` and `s.length() == 0`?

Comment: The problem is that `s == ""` doesn't cover all empty strings (for example not those derived using substring, or using `new String(...)`, etc.

Comment: Besides that, instead of `s.length() == 0` or `s.equals("")`, you can simply use `s.isEmpty()`.